# Error in R function readGPS: gpsbabel not found

Tags: r, gps, gpx

I'm trying to download a gpx file from the YOURS routing API (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS#Routing_API) and upload the file to R using the readGPS function contained in the maptools package.

Here is the code:

```
require(utils)
require(maptools)


URL <- 'http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/saveas.php?type=gpx&data=5.62373%2053.01,5.62359%2053.01014,5.62336%2053.01024,5.62314%2053.010303'

download.file(URL, 'tmpTrip.gpx')
gpx.raw <- readGPS(i='gpx', f='tmpTrip.gpx', type='t')
```

And the error I receive:

```
Error in readGPS(i = "gpx", f = "tmpTrip.gpx", type = "t") : 
  gpsbabel not found
```

I do have installed gpsbabel and I can see the gpx file correctly downloaded in my working directory.
My system and R version are:
Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1, running on Intel Core i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz, 4GB RAM, 32 bit OS.

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figuring it out the hard way, I found that `readGPS()` calls `Sys.which` which is a function that tries to find where a file is located on the system. `?Sys.which` doesn't say it that clearly but (at least on Windows) for it to work, you need to add the install path of gpsbabel to your path.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [GPSBabel](https://www.gpsbabel.org/) installed in your working directory as well, this should work.

For me, I changed the WD:

```
 setwd("C:/Program Files (x86)/GPSBabel")
```

And then my code

```
 gpx.raw <- readGPS(i = "gpx", f = "C:/Users/Desktop/waypoints.gpx", type="w")
```

worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users:

```
setwd("/Applications/GPSBabelFE.app")
```